# Hitting enter on comment spell check

Tags: bug, comments

This "bug" has been annoying me for years. I use Firefox, not sure if it happens in other browsers.

When spell checking I will select the word I want to correct to in the right click menu and hit enter.

If I write text in a question/answer box, the text is replaced and the cursor remains at the end of the corrected word. In a comment box this causes the comment to be posted, so I often leave half written comments until I finish writing them.

This doesn't happen if I use the mouse to select the corrected word. It appears as if even though I am pressing enter in a right click menu, the comment box is still picking it up and taking it as a signal to post a comment.

Anyone else experienced this/know how to fix it?

Comment: @JonClements Most text areas don't perform some special action when you press enter.  It just adds a line break to the text area.  The SO code to submit the comment when the user hits enter apparently doesn't play nice with browser features doing the same thing.

Comment: @Servy ahhh... yes... that clarified it and that dupe was useful to read as it made it even clearer what the issue is. Thanks.